# sqlalchemy grant permission in Base.metadata.create_all

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

Is there a way to grant permissions when creating a new table using sqlalchemy?
The only way I see to do it now is to execute an sql "GRANT ALL ON TABLE blabla to whomever;" everytime I do a Base.metadata.create_all(...)

Answer (score 2):

I use PostgreSQL database with psycopg2 backend. After `create_all` I execute:

```
import models
from psycopg2 import sql

for table in models.Base.metadata.tables.values():
    connection.connection.cursor().execute(
        sql.SQL('GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON {} TO {}').format(
            sql.Identifier(table.name), sql.Identifier('bob')))
```